# Incrementing a number with JavaScript returns an error

Tags: javascript

```
var count = {
    digit: 0,
    increment: function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            count.digit++;
        }, 500);
        if (count == 10) {
            count.increment = null;
        }
    }
};
document.write("The number is " + count.digit);
count.increment();
```

The result is: "The number is 0" but it does not increment. Why?

Comment: i think the `count == 10` part have to go inside the interval as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your if statement inside the setInterval also `count.digit == 0`

This is a bit cleaner IMO

```
var count = {
    digit: 0,
    increment: function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (++count.digit == 10)
                clearInterval(interval);
            document.write("The number is " + count.digit);
        }, 500);
    }
};
count.increment();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"A string" + "another string" == "A new string"
```

… and a new string is not a live updating version of the combination of the two strings that formed it in the first place.

Even if it was, then `document.write` takes a string, expresses it as HTML, then adds it to the document — so that wouldn't live update it either.

You would need to use DOM methods to modify the HTML document instead of the string. The WSC has a good introduction to manipulating HTML with DOM: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-and-modifying-html/

You have another problem in that setting `count.interval` to `null` wouldn't stop the function incrementing the counter every half second since:

1. You aren't overwriting the function that is being called every half second
2. Replacing a reference to a function with something else, doesn't stop that function from existing unless *all* references to it are overwritten, and setInterval would maintain the reference.

You need to keep the return value from setInterval and use it to [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).